# Disable the "dark" theme on Vuetify 3

Tags: vuetify.js

We are using Vuetify 3 with custom colors and we just want to disable the "dark" theme, and thus ignore the prefers-color-scheme of the browser.

I cannot find anything on the documentation. Even if a define a custom theme, the dark theme is always used when prefers-color-scheme:dark.

Thanks !